# Linux photo manager with easy print ordering

Tags: linux, photography

Is there a photo manager for Linux that makes it easy to order prints in any of the following ways?

- Via an upload plugin for some photo retailer.
- By tagging the files for printing and exporting the tagged files to removable media.
- By creating those photo order files that some cameras used to produce back around 2007.  (I forget what the file format was called and I don't know if the idea ever took off.)